# vim colo directive ignored in console

Tags: vim, colors, tmux, gnome-terminal, vimrc

I have the following in my .vimrc:

```
if has("gui_running")
    colo desert
    " ...
else 
    colo distinguished
    " ...
endif
```

gvim works fine.  When I open vim in gnome-terminal in tmux, the `colo` above is seemingly ignored. Other directives in the else block execute, but when I enter `:colo` it returns `default`.

When I manually enter `colo distinguished` it works.

I have the usual entries `set t_Co=256`, etc. elsewhere. So this isn't merely a problem of getting 256-color gnome terminal / tmux.

OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  vim 7.3 2010 Aug 15

Comment: If the answer I posted isn't sufficient you should probably show your whole vimrc

Comment: my whole vimrc is a mess. I probably need troubleshooting suggestions. Perhaps start rebuilding my vimrc from scratch?

Comment: Commenting out half the file and doing a binary search normally works pretty well. If anything post the whole if block if you think it's not affected by anything else

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem by essentially rebuilding my .vimrc, piece-by-piece. I will delete this question shortly.

Comment: I made my dotfiles public: https://github.com/noahlz/dotfiles/blob/59a4e8b50b35d8b5b68b56ca295b5153867718aa/vimrc

Comment: So everything works right? do you know what the problem was?

Comment: Yes, it is all great now! Thanks for finally giving me the push to clean up my vimrc! I am not going to agonize on over the root cause. Yak = shaved :)